# How to get All the active shipping methods and shipping rate and set minimum shipping rate method in quote programmatically in magento2?

Tags: magento2

How to get All the active shipping methods and shipping rate and set minimum shipping rate method in quote programmatically in magento2

Answer (score 1):

You can get active shipping method list using this code.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Block;

class Shippingmethodinfo extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $shipconfig;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Config $shipconfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->shipconfig = $shipconfig;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }


    public function getActiveShippingList()
    {


        $activeCarriers = $this->shipconfig->getActiveCarriers();
        $shippingmethods = array();
        foreach($activeCarriers as $carrierCode => $carrierModel)
        {
            $options = array();
            if($carrierMethods = $carrierModel->getAllowedMethods())
            {
                foreach ($carrierMethods as $methodCode => $method)
                {
                    $code = $carrierCode.'_'.$methodCode;
                    $options[]= array('value'=>$code,'label'=>$method);
                }
                $carrierTitle = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('carriers/'.$carrierCode.'/title');

            }
            $shippingmethods[]=array('value'=>$options,'label'=>$carrierTitle); 

        }

        return $shippingmethods;
    }
}
```